# Как правильно переключить с Qdialog на QMainWindow?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt, qt-designer, qstackedwidget

Нужна помощь, мне нужно сделать авторизацию и потом убрать поля ввода и показать другой функционал.

Я хотел сделать переключение с помощью кнопки, нашел ролик там идет переключение между `QDialog`, я хотел попробовать переключить на `QMainWindow`, но ошибка:

> Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)

Можно ли просто скрывать кнопки и `input`, и показать другой функционал в одном окне, чтобы было проще, или лучше сделать в разных окнах?

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi


class Login(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Login, self).__init__()
        loadUi("login.ui", self)
        self.singBtn.clicked.connect(self.loginfnc)

    def loginfnc(self):
        email = self.email.text()
        password = self.password.text()
        print("email", email, "password", password)
        mainapp = MainWindow()
        widget.addWidget(mainapp)
        widget.setCurrentWidget(widget.currentIndex() + 1)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        loadUi("mainWindowApp.ui", self)
        self.singBtn.clicked.connect(self.excelparsing)

    def excelparsing(self):
        print("excel")


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
mainWindow = Login()
widget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
widget.addWidget(mainWindow)
widget.setGeometry(500, 250, 350, 300)
widget.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, [**QStackedWidget**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html) это то, что вам лючше всего использовать.
Но код написан не очень красиво.

Первая ваше ошибка в том, что вы не предоставляете
**минимально-воспроизводимый пример**, который демонстрирует проблему
и проверить ваш код не представляется возможным.
Вы не предоставили модули **login.ui** и **mainWindowApp.ui**.

Второе, что вам надо сделать - это **запустить ваше
приложение в консоли/терминале/CMD** и вы получите реальную ошибку,
а не:

> Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)

---

Мне кажется что ошибка у вас в строке:

```
widget.setCurrentWidget(widget.currentIndex() + 1)
```

замените ее на строку:

```
widget.setCurrentIndex(1)
```

и попробуйте еще раз запустить приложение.

Comment: А как добавить UI файлы,чтоб вы смогли воспроизвести данный код?

Comment: @ПетяГерман UI файлы добавляются точно так как и PY файлы. Только я не понял, то что я написал в ответе не решило вашу проблему?

Comment: Все помогло, спасибо

Comment: @ПетяГерман  пожалуйста.